# Adding library with and without resources in android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I'm new to android development. I wanted to implement Navigation Drawer feature in my application, which requires android.support.v4.jar file to be included in my project. I'm using Android Studio to develop my application so I included the **compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"** in my build.gradle file as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html. My project is working fine, I was able to successfully include my library. I did adding library without resources.

What I couldn't figure out is the difference between adding library without resources and adding library with resources. Does adding library with resources mean including some sample project?

Thanks

Comment: I think this should also be tagged gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android Studio projects using Gradle (which is what your project is), there isn't an important distinction between libraries with resources and without resources. The Gradle build system's support for Android is more advanced than anything available to Eclipse and can support libraries with and without resources the same way (you just add the `compile` statement to your dependencies as you have; you can also do it more easily via the Project Structure dialog).

In Eclipse, if you want to include a library with resources, you have to add it as a project (similar to an Android Studio module) to ensure the resources get included directly; there you can't include resourceful libraries as simple jar files.

Comment: To be more clear, if any of my projects require Facebook API's then it can called as importing libraries with resources. Whereas any project with require only support libraries (like android.support.v4 jar) it's called importing library without resources.